# Cannot resolve symbol GsonConverterFactory

Tags: android, gradle

I get this error message if I try to use GsonConvertFactory:

> Cannot resolve Symbol `GsonConverterFactory`

I am using it like this:

```
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            //.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

This is my gradle file (Module: app):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}
```

Answer (score 19):

[GsonConverterFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson) resides in following dependency so, add this in your `build.gradle` as dependency.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

To this

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Answer (score 1):

you shoul add these library to build.gradle file

**compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'**

```css
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add gson converter factory gradle verson
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:latest.version'